# Is learning Django without initial knowledge of Python possible?

Tags: python, django

I am coming from procedural PHP with fair amount of knowledge on it. I want to learn Django but I don't have initial knowledge of Python. Can I learn Django at the same time also learning Python? Thank you so much!

Comment: It's usually best to learn the basic language before moving on to frameworks. I've learned JavaScript before jQuery (even though it's absolutely unnecessary, one can easily learn jQuery without JavaScript).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450986/can-i-learn-django-without-python

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.  You'll be writing Python code.  In Python.   You'll have to learn Python.

A little bit of your project will be CSS, JavaScript and HTML with template tags inserted.

Most of your project will be Python.

Comment: No.  You'll need to actually spend a week actually learning the language, data structures, OO programming and parts of the Python library.  If you don't learn OO programming in Python first, you'll spend twice as much time searching SO for answers to questions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for those pointers. I am now looking for best resources to learn Python.

Comment: I think these series of videos are great: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKTZoB2Vjuk&ob=av3e it's for people with some prior knowledge of programming...

Comment: I +1 this. "Django is just python" is actually an important part of the philosophy of the framework. Even the setting files and the model definitions are in Python.

Comment: @freakysquash i endorse [python version of how to think like a computer scientist](http://openbookproject.net/thinkcs/python/english2e/) as a Python primer

Comment: @S.Lott: the reason of the debate is probably because it's an a strongly opiniated answer. What about replacing the definitive "No" by "You can, but I don't recommand it because....". I don't edit your post since it's a subjective matter, I may write something you don't really think.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any real debate in these comments.  Perhaps I'm missing something. It's a strongly-worded answer for a reason.  Over the last 3 decades of programming, I've seen a lot of bad education, and a lot of good education.  I'm repeating my experience in this answer.  A short-cut leads to a long delay.  Also.  80% of Django programming **is** python.  You can't do Django without Python.  There's an essential isomorphism there.

Comment: A nice article: Learning Python via Django Considered Harmful http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2012/12/11/learning-python-via-django-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 6):

Yes! It's called 'immersion.' You learn Spanish by speaking Spanish. You learn Python by writing Python. Having a concrete project ("I'm going to make webapp that does *xyz* in Django") in mind gives you something to work *on* and *towards*. If you have the time and the determination to stick with it, and useful resources at your disposal (google, SO, docs), this is a great way to learn. It helps to be a certain type of person (stubborn, willful, patient).

Comment: You are talking about writting a novel in spanish prior to knowing it with the Django/python example. Plus, with learning spanish immersion works because making mistakes has little importance. When learning Django, not only will you be very unproductive not knowing python but you will make very poor design decisions that will lead to a terrible project to maintain. And worst, you will learn very bad programming habbit, leadding you to code in python like in "insert you previous language" because you tried to just "make it work", 'it' being too complex to focus on learning the right things.

Comment: @e-satis - Not to start some sort of war here, but the question was not "Can I make a production quality site using Django without knowing Python?" - The question was about learning.  The answer is *yes*, you can *learn* Django and Python at the same time.  Albeit some may find it more challenging, but it *is* in fact possible.  Through the course of learning, you'll pick up good habits, ask questions, and each attempt will get better and better.  No one is suggesting he write the next Facebook on the first try.

Comment: "but it is in fact possible".  Many things are possible.  It's possible to create a working Django app knowing nothing at all.  Generate a lot of random code and it's *possible* that it might work.  What's possible is a far cry from what's practical.  It's somewhat more practical to learn Python first.

Comment: @Mike: well you can learn django without knowing programming at all in that case. But would you recommand it?

Comment: @e-satis - No, I don't think I'd recommend that to someone who had *zero* programming experience what-so-ever.

Comment: @mike is making a better defense than I could. Everybody else is giving Negative Nellie answers to this question. Of course it's subjective, and it's not the best way for all people, but sometimes just jumping in and figuring things out as you go along is an excellent way to go.

Comment: @benauthor: Having seen a fair number of Stack Overflow questions, I'd hold off on "excellent" and perhaps suggest "workable" or "possible if  you have the time".

Comment: The reason why we have a strong opinion on this is not because we want to be right, but because we have a good experience on that matter. S.Lott and I both have the golden Python tag as we do Python for a living, he got the Django gold tag, and I train people to use Django, sometimes in deep Africa. This is not a "my answer is bigger than yours" debate, it's really a about the experience we got with the product. The OP is not going to die if he choose to start to learn Django without starting to learn Django first. We just think he would not be making the best of it.

Comment: 8 years later this question still gets eyeballs and I still feel the same way. Folks in this thread suggest "Learn Python First" ... what, by reading a book cover to cover and doing "hello world" and other simple exercises? Works for some people. Other people find that approach hella boring and need something more concrete to attach their learning process. Django has great docs and community so there are worse contexts to start out with. Me, I'm not special, and I bootstrapped in just this way and ultimately made a fulfilling career out of programming. You can too, if you're tenacious.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest it's possible, but definitely steepens the learning curve.  When learning a new language, I usually enjoy using it to actually do something useful rather than just writing `Hello World` programs.  Learning Django while learning Python at the same time might be a good way to do this.

I did learn Ruby at the same time as I learned Rails, and I did find myself having to lookup basic Ruby syntax every 30 seconds, but I eventually got the hang of it.  I found that looking at some of the weird Rails constructs pushed me into having to learn various Ruby features that I might have not run into on my own as well, so that was an advantage.

I would say give it a shot, and if you find the whole thing overwhelming, then back off a bit and focus on some command line scripts or other simple programs.

Comment: I also considered RoR and some Java Web Frameworks, but ended up to Django/Python. If there's another PHP like language aside from Perl, that will be my choice, but I can't find one.

Comment: I tried jumping into Django without a grounding in Python, or indeed a grounding in programming in general. It definitely made it harder.

Comment: True.  But the question very specifically said "is [it] possible", not "is it easy".  So my official answer is "Yes."

Comment: What are you talking about? Hello World should be the first goal when learning any language!

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:  no.

Long answer:  Learning a framework for a particular language is essentially taking the basic syntax with its nuances, and adding a new level of complexity to it.  You're coming from a different language with a different semantic structure, so you would require time to both understand what Python's doing, and how it's doing it with Django.

Answer (score 0):

Learning Python through Django is like learning PHP through wordpress. You will learn python, but Django is it's own beast. If you are experienced in another language or web programming then you will be fine jumping into Django. If this is your first language then you need to learn basic python first.

> I also recommend something lighter like Flask to start with as you will use more raw python and learn to setup your own scaffold and folder structure which will help you understand Django behind the scenes.